# Powershell: Can you import a separate copy of a module?

Tags: powershell, module

I wanted to make a logging module, which would be imported into all my code going forward, but I've learned that when you import a module a second time, you don't get a new copy of the module.  You get the SAME module. So if the module has any variables, changes to those variables from one place will be reflected everywhere. That means my logging module wouldn't be able to accept any parameter settings, since those settings would be defined by the first thing that imports it, and thereafter ignored.

Is there any way to make it so that each time I import my logging module, I get a separate copy of it with separate variables?

Comment: You can try `Import-Module <ModuleName> -Force`. The `-Force` Parameter should overwrite the currently loaded module.

Comment: That will unload the module before it reloads it. It won't leave you with separate copies of the module.

Comment: Sorry I took it to mean you didn't want the variables or whatnot carried forward. As far as I know there's not an easy way to load multiple copies.

Comment: If you want it to use different variables it sounds like you need to redesign your logging module to be accommodating to your needs.

Comment: So then I probably want to adjust my module so that I create a Logging object, and use the object to record logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly there is not any way to have multiple of the same module as the registry that handles this is "global" for the given context (either in the current session or within a module, so a import-module within a module would not expose the imported module to the global record)

I would also advice against this behavior as it messes with how cmdlets are looked up when you call the actual command: when calling write-log would this mean Write-log in module 1 or 2?

If you want to log to different files within the same command, you could append a [string]$stream or something to your cmdlet parameters that defines what logfile the current sent message will end up in. Or you could do it based upon what command calls the log command with `$Caller = (Get-PSCallStack)[1].Command`